# Export GPS file in Lambert 93 for Illustrator manipulation

Tags: qgis, gpx, illustrator, lambert-conformal-conic

In Illustrator, I use some French IGN maps (1/50.000 scale) Lambert 93.
I want to put on some GPX files to the right position for sure.
I use QGIS to import the GPX file, I modify the reference to Lambert 93 (`EPSG:2154`). I export it in DXF file. When I open it in Illustrator, it's impossible to have the GPX file in the right place on my map. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

How do you "modify the reference"? Setting the CRS of the layer is not enough. You should `Save as ...` as Shapefile (don't forget a new name), choose EPSG:2154 as CRS, and add the layer to the canvas.

Now you can look if map and your file data align, by switching "On the fly-Projection" off  and on. Your reprojected data should rest in place, while your GPX layer will vanish when checked off.

Then you can export it as DXF.

Comment: Thanks. I understand all your steps but it doesn't work... Always the same problem in Illustrator...

Comment: Thanks. I understand all your steps, it works ! in Illustrator i have to reduce the size of the path to be perfect align with my carto. I think it's normal.
any idea to make same things for several GPX ?

Comment: Once you have a shapefile in the right projection, you can copy and paste the data from every GPX file into it. Only the shapefile layer has to be in edit mode. Select a GPX layer, draw a rectangle around all with the yellow tool, Edit->Copy, select the shapefile Edit->paste

Comment: Maybe the following helps you: Create a shapefile of the extent of your raster file with Raster -> Misc. -> Tile index. The Raster file should be the only one in its directory. Then put the GPX data into the same shapefile as mentioned above, and export it to DXF for Illustrator. Other chance would be to use print composer output.